# GNOME: Bottom task bar is missing/blank after upgrade

Tags: gnome, desktop, kali-linux, desktop-environment, gnome-panel

I am running kali linux, which has gnome. I just updated with

`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

and that completed without incident, only a little while after did I realise that my bottom taskbar was missing(well technically just blank(black)). The one where running programs are displayed as well as the 4 buttons that allow switching between workspaces. I have searched around for the last hour, and tried a few things, such as

```
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/panel && killall gnome-panel
```

and a couple of variations thereof.

Nothing has worked so far. I also tried:

```
apt-get build-dep gnome-panel
```

which installed a ton of stuff to my surprise... but still, no fix.

If I type `gnome-panel` into the terminal I get the message:

```
Cannot register the panel shell: there is already one running.
```

So clearly, it's not gone(anyway the top bar with menus and shutdown options etc. is still there), it's just the bottom bar... I also noticed that while I say it's missing, it's technically still there, albeit just a black unresponsive bar across the bottom of the screen. So I guess my real question is, why is it not showing anything? And can anybody please help me out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out that for some reason the settings for my bottom panel(taskbar) had been altered. To access the menu for the panels(top & bottom bars), I needed to hold *Alt and then Right-click*. This opened a little menu where I could select *Add to panel...* which opens another menu of things you can add to the taskbar. What I needed to add was **'Windows List'**, which solved my problem.

Comment: I had to explicitly enable the "Window List" under Extensions in the gnome-tweaks application.

Answer (score 4):

Open an application named Tweaks.
Then go to Extensions.
Enable window list.
Done

Comment: You can also search for Extensions then you enable the extensions you want as he mentioned above

Answer (score 3):

On the latest version of Kali 2.x, I had the same exact issue.  `Alt + Right Click` didn't do anything, but if you do the following it gets out of Kiosk mode

`right click`

select `applications -> settings -> panel`

it will say there is no panel running and are you sure you want to start one.. I clicked `execute` and it stopped running kiosk mode.

Answer (score 1):

In case your right click doesn't work (mine didn't on the desktop), do this:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. In the "Application Finder" search box, enter **"Panel"**

   Follow what **Erik** said

Answer (score 1):

This command helped me to get back side toolbar:

```
apt-get install gnome-core kali-defaults kali-root-login desktop-base
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu running Gnome 40 you need to toggle the `Ubuntu AppIndicators` toggle in `Extensions`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

- gnome-tweak-tool → Extensions → Window List

Answer (score 0):

**100 PERCENT SOLUTION.**

Click on "Applications" (on the TOP bar, just beside with "Places" option) → then click on "Activities overview" (at the end of the bottom of the options list) → then go to in the "Dash to dock setting" with the help of right-click on "extreme right option" → then go to "Position and size" option on the top → "Intelligent Autohide" → Disable it.

Your problem has been solved :)

Comment: This "100 PERCENT SOLUTION" is not working for me.